# PostGIS not recognizing geometry type after writing to database with geopandas

Tags: postgis, geopandas

I have a PostGIS database set up that is spatially enabled.

```
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/{dbname}')
```

I have a valid geopandas dataframe (i.e., if I export as .shp or .gpkg I can load into a GIS app with no errors) with a geometry column named 'geometry'. I write these data to the database with:

```
gdf.to_postgis('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='append', index_label='id')
```

If I read all records from this table:

```
gpd.read_postgis('table_name', con=engine, geom_col='geometry')
```

I get the following warning:

```
SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'geometry' of column 'geometry' pandas_sql.meta.reflect(only=[sql])
```

If I try to execute an postgresql statement such as:

```
gpd.read_postgis('SELECT DISTINCT(st_cnty_fips) FROM table_name', con=self.engine, geom_col='geometry')
```

I get an error:

```
line 65, in _df_to_geodf
    raise ValueError("Query missing geometry column '{}'".format(geom_col))
ValueError: Query missing geometry column 'geometry'
```

Using PGAdmin4 I can see that the column exists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Geopandas requires a geometry columna after filtering out geometry additionally or adding it should work.

The parameter geom_col='geometry' allows you to specify the name of this column that geopandas needs.

Need to add geometries.

For example:

```
SELECT your_query_with_out_geom, geometry FROM table_name;
```

In your case, could:

```
gpd.read_postgis('SELECT DISTINCT(st_cnty_fips), geometry FROM table_name', con=self.engine, geom_col='geometry')
```